# Does software utilizing OpenSSL needs to be specially compiled for ECDSA support?

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache-traffic-server

I am attempting to configure my Apache Traffic Server to use ECDSA cert/key. However, I got the following error message when connecting with openssl s_client

```
 routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv 3 alert handshake
```

and if I attempt to connect it directly with Firefox I am prompted that no common cipher is available.

I am pretty sure that the certs/keys are generated correctly as I was able to establish a connection with the same cert/key with openssl s_server and openssl s_client.

So that makes me wondering if I need to compile ATS specially to make use of ECDSA certificates.

Comment: What about attempting to connect to Traffic Server's SSL listener with `openssl s_client`?  That'll tell us whether the client or the server is the one having a problem.  There shouldn't be a need to recompile, but then again I'm not seeing anything in the Traffic Server docs about changing the cipher suite, just protocol version.

Comment: @shane-madden Tested, and the result is here: https://www.box.com/shared/d9e113be090c52d61c78 (sorry on mobile and can't do copy-and-paste) The documentation online is partially outdated. There is one option to set ciphers and I've set to ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA with server honour cipher(I don't know what's the term?) turned on. Both server and client support this cipher as tested in the s_server and s_client test.

Comment: By the way, if I use a RSA certificate instead everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Sounds like I can't mention you, so @ShaneMadden

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like yes.

A quick Googling turns out [this](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,11737,11790) post which pointed out that "this requires elliptic curve to be specified to use for ephemeral ECDH keys" and thus if you are going to use a ECDSA, you will need the software to specially support it.